# How do I create an inheritable Semaphore in .NET?

Tags: .net, winapi, process, semaphore

I am trying to create a Win32 Semaphore object which is *inheritable*.  This means that any child processes I launch may automatically have the right to act on the same Win32 object.

My code currently looks as follows:

```
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0, 10);
Process process = Process.Start(pathToExecutable, arguments);
```

But the semaphore object in this code cannot be used by the child process.

---

The code I am writing is a port of come working C++.  The old C++ code achieves this by the following:

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES security = {0};
security.nLength = sizeof(security);
security.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
HANDLE semaphore = CreateSemaphore(&security, 0, LONG_MAX, NULL);
```

Then later when `CreateProcess` is called the `bInheritHandles` argument is set to `TRUE`.

(In both the C# and C++ case I am using the same child process (which is C++).  It takes the semaphore ID on command line, and uses the value directly in a call to `ReleaseSemaphore`.)

---

I suspect I need to construct a special `SemaphoreSecurity` or `ProcessStartInfo` object, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to just wrap the C++ code which creates the Semaphore and launches the child process, and call it via P/Invoke (or use C++/CLI).

Answer (score 0):

You can just PInvoke to CreateSemaphore and ReleaseSemaphore, just remember to use the same name as the forth parameter of CreateSemaphore.